# Optimal rootflags for rootfs for ext4 file system running on USB thumdrive

Tags: debian, filesystems, ext4, live-usb

I have made myself a bootable USB Debian 7 thumbdrive, using `debootstrap`. It boots nicely – but occasionally freezes for a bit. I can see the load average is much higher than the running tasks should indicate. I wonder if maybe the default ext4 mounting parameters don't work well in this scenario. Are there things I can change (even at the risk of data loss?) to make it run faster.

I am assuming I could add something to rootflags in the kernel boot params in GRUB2. What flags could I use?

Comment: I don't see how the mounting parameters — or the filesystem creation flags, for that matter — are related to a high load average. During boot, it's normal to have a high load average: all those services are starting up. Do you still have a high load average when the system should be quiescent? When the system freezes, is there disk I/O, and from what processes?

Comment: `noatime` or `diratime` may improve disk performance. other than that, I don't know.